# PostgreSQL Select filled columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a database where not all columns will be filled. I just want to select columns with minimum one value. So if the column is empty from top to bottom it should not be selected. All I could find looking for an answer where searches along the rows so if a column is empty the hole row will not be selected.

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ "receiver_id" ║ "gps_week" ║ "gps_second" ║ "latitude" ║ "longitude" ║ "altitude_msl" ║ "altitude_hae" ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║             1 ║            ║              ║ 38.0517465 ║ 15.660851   ║                ║ 691.379883     ║
║             1 ║            ║              ║ 38.0517465 ║ 15.660851   ║                ║ 691.389404     ║
║             1 ║            ║              ║ 38.0517465 ║ 15.660851   ║                ║ 691.402344     ║
║             1 ║            ║              ║ 38.0517465 ║ 15.6608509  ║                ║ 691.413818     ║
║             1 ║            ║              ║ 38.0517465 ║ 15.6608508  ║                ║ 691.425659     ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

In the example table I want to return

```
receiver_id, latitude, longitude, altitude_hae
```

Comment: So you want a different number of columns each time you run the statement? That's not possible.

Comment: "*not all collumns will be filled*" - then why do you have them in your database in the first place?

Comment: i run many trials in some i gather more or different variables

Comment: when i select and load the date from one trial i just want the variables i filled there if i select more trials i want all variables wich where recorded in minimum one trial

Comment: thank you for your comments then i have to pull everything into python and select there with pandas

Comment: @TomStober coordinates with elevation or time dimensions are better handled within a `geometry` or `geography` column from `PostGIS`. Storing them in separated columns might be convenient at a first glance, but when you start dealing with spatial queries you'll most certainly regret this decision. cheers